# Where to set username and password in git_clone in libgit2?

Tags: git-clone, libgit2

#### Hello, the question is, when I using libgit2 to clone a repo, it will result : "Failed to send request: A security error occurred", the code is:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "include/git2.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "git2.lib")

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    git_threads_init();

    git_repository* repo = NULL;
    git_clone_options opts = GIT_CLONE_OPTIONS_INIT;
    int iRetVal;

    opts.bare = true;
    iRetVal = git_clone(&repo, "https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2.git", "C:\\test", &opts);
    if( (iRetVal < 0) && (giterr_last() != NULL) )
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, giterr_last()->message, "gittest", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
    }
    if( repo != NULL )
        git_repository_free(repo);

    git_threads_shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

#### The libgit2 version is 0.21.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to populate the `remote_callbacks` property of the `git_clone_options`.

Thoses **[online::clone.c tests](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/tests/online/clone.c#L281-L330)** which perform an authenticated cloning should you getting started.